# import Axes3D: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, 3d, axes

So when I am trying to plot a 3d graph, I get `import Axes3D: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

I am using Python 2.7 32 bit. I think that MATPLOTLIB is 64 bit and I cannot find the 32 bit version. Can someone suggest me some alternatives or workarounds?

Comment: You could try and download then install the pre-built binaries from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)

Comment: I am trying but my pip is giving this error
'ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 13:40:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
The thing is Anaconda is not my default

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Check the comment again, I edited it